# Scala sorting Options

Tags: scala

If I have a case class like this

```
case class Foo(bar: Option[String])
```

why does this work

```
scala> val l = List(Foo(Some("b")), Foo(Some("a")), Foo(Some("c")))
l: List[Foo] = List(Foo(Some(b)), Foo(Some(a)), Foo(Some(c)))
scala> l.sortBy(_.bar)
res1: List[Foo] = List(Foo(Some(a)), Foo(Some(b)), Foo(Some(c)))
```

but not this

```
scala> l.sortWith((x,y) => x.bar > y.bar)
<console>:11: error: value > is not a member of Option[String]
          l.sortWith((x,y) => x.bar > y.bar)
```

If I want to sort a `List` of `Option[String]` in descending order, is it just simpler to use `sortBy` and then `reverse` the list?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because `sorted` but not `sortWith` takes an implicit parameter of type `Ordering`, and `Ordering` knows about options.  With `sortWith`, you're on your own.  And with `<` you're also on your own.

You can access the same machinery in a clunky fashion:

```
l.sortWith((a,b) => Ordering[Option[String]].gt(a.bar,b.bar))
```

or get the nicer version with an import (but now you'll be able to compare `Option`s anywhere based on their contents; hopefully that is what you want):

```
import scala.math.Ordered._
l.sortWith((a,b) => a.bar > b.bar)
```

The first is such a mouthful that unless you're really pressed for performance, it's easier to just `.sorted.reverse.`.  (And if you are really pressed for performance, you'd probably be better off handling the option logic manually, e.g. `a.bar.isEmpty || !b.bar.isEmpty || a.bar.get < b.bar.get`.)

If you're going to do multiple sorts, it's hard to beat the second for clarity.  For just one test, I'd still probably favor `.sorted.reverse`.

Comment: You could add to your answer solution with `import math.Ordered._`. In this case `l.sortWith((x,y) => x.bar > y.bar)` works as expected.

Comment: @senia - Indeed, that would be a good idea.  Not sure why I thought one would want to do it the manual way.  Reflexive aversion to extra imports, maybe?